# WebM with VP9 vs MP4 with H.264 AVC which one is best overall

Tags: android, video, mp4, android-videoview, codec

I have used `VideoView` and load MP4 file of length 1 minute.

The problem is it start's after delay.
I want it to start immediately so which codec and byte rate to choose.

Share your experience if any one related to video codec.
I want to see comparison between these two types.

**Loading speed, length and file size and quality ratio**

Comment: This all depends on the settings of your encoder, not that much on container and decoder used (in this case).

Comment: @incBrain yes it's depends on bite rate etc but like json decoding is faster than xml. Similarly there must be speed comparison of video codec from decoding to rendering first frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. MP4 usually has all index tables at the end of the file, so it may require to scan the whole file on the disk in order to start playback. 
   You may convert into MP4 file, optimized for streaming, so that tables are at the beginning.
   MPEG TS (Transport stream) also is loaded quickly. 
   Probably Webm will load faster than "standard" MP4,  but I am not so familiar with Webm format.
2. All PCs and smartphones have hardware based AVC (H.264) video decoder. VP9 is mostly decoded in software. So presumably, AVC will be easier to decode for your computer.
   Quality or size of VP9 can be better than AVC only if you use HD. On smaller videos quality should be more or less equal.
   There are many useful tools to encode AVC, and not so much for VP9. Using ffmpeg and proper settings like 2-pass encoding you can compress AVC harder than VP9.

So I recommend to use AVC, and optimized MP4.